# DexFile.loadDex hangs

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

Any android experts could shed some light why this method could hang?

When I pause the thread and look at the stack:

```
Thread [<13> Thread-15] (Suspended) 
DexFile.openDexFile(String, String, int) line: not available [native method]    
DexFile.<init>(String, String, int) line: 105   
DexFile.loadDex(String, String, int) line: 144  
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521
```

...you can see it is hanging in the native method DexFile.openDexFile, it never returns.

This is causing serious problems for an application we are writing. It happens randomly and so suggests a race condition of some sort between several threads but I connect detect and deadlocks and plus I would expect the native method to return me something, even an exception would be nice!!

Thanks in advance

I am using Android 2.2 Nexus One Device, I am deploying the application from eclipse to the device. To be sure I totally uninstall the application and re-power the device and I still see the above problem randomly.

UPDATE: I retried on an Android 2.3.3 emulator (API 10) and have the same problem. I am now convinced there is a major bug here. I have created a simple test case to show the problem. Basically I add a single dexified jar to the assets folder of an android project. On startup I copy this file to the application data area. I then kick off x threads and within each thread load this dexified jar file using DexFile.loadDex but giving a different output file name for the generated optimized dex file. If you pick x to be say 30 threads you are almost guaranteed to see several threads hang.

Just to be sure I repeated the test where each thread is given it's own unique dexified jar file. Same problem occurs.

The only LogCat output I see that may give a hint to what is going wrong:

02-23 11:59:23.097: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12598): DexOpt: sleeping on flock(/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex)
02-23 11:59:23.138: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12602): DexOpt: sleeping on flock(/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex)
02-23 11:59:23.357: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12602): DexOpt: sleeping on flock(/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex)
02-23 11:59:23.419: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12598): DexOpt: sleeping on flock(/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex)
02-23 11:59:23.528: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12608): DexOpt: sleeping on flock(/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex)
02-23 11:59:23.577: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12598): DexOpt: sleeping on flock(/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@services.jar@classes.dex)
02-23 11:59:23.698: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12606): DexOpt: sleeping on flock(/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex)

The other interesting thing is, as an example I have a dexified jar file

myjar.jar   (size 5031)

Each thread that opens this dex file creates a file

myjar.jarX.dex (where X is a unique integer for each thread) (size 4152)

The threads that do not complete the DexFile.loadDex call have still managed to create a myjar.jarX.dex file but the file is of size 3496

I believe there is some form a race condition deep down in the Dalvik native code. This is a big showstopper for us. Any suggestions how best to proceed?